# failed to create jvm:error code -6 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i set -XmxheapSize:-Xmx2g in Custom VM Options
and run jps -lvm in console after this android studio not lunch and error

> failed to create jvm:error code -6 android studio

i restart pc and re-install android studio but not working!!!

please hlep

my system operation windows 10 64-bit

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a corrupt custom vmoptions file
To fix, edit the file, which for me was here:

```
C:\Users\<WindowsUser>\.AndroidStudio2.3\studio64.exe.vmoptions
```

Ensure options are specified one on each line.
e.g.

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
-Xms750m
-Xmx750m
```

Save the file and rerun Android Studio.

Comment: Correct. This the root cause of this problem. But not able to edit vmoptions file and save it.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked jvm.dll in

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\client? To me, I found it at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server

Comment: i found this directory:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\server

Comment: is there jvm.dll present in it?

Comment: i set -XmxheapSize:-Xmx2g
and run jps -lvm in console after this not working android studio

Comment: The JAVA_HOME should contain the path of the 64-bit JDK.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31 is the path of a JRE. Normally the JDK directory should be something like jdk1.8.0_31 in your case, and the JAVA_HOME would store the absolute path of this directory, without the bin directory. Try searching for that directory under C:/Program Files (C:/Program Files(x86) is usually for 32-bit installations).

Answer (score 0):

**How I have solved the error.** Frst I played so many times with JAVA_HOME and Path sections doesnt work at all. Then Removed the Android Studio so reinstalled not worked again. Also I have played with the values of ***C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin studio.exe.vmoptions*** not worked again. Last thing that I done is the picture below; I removed the .AndroidStuido1.5 (3gb)not worked again finnaly I removed .AndroidStuido2.2 and started A.S again it worked. I am not sure what caused the error maybe there is some kind of capacity that I have reached by creating so many project, dont know. By the way I returned to jdk1.7. It was jdk1.8 before actualy I recomend to remove the .AndroidStuido(version) first. Hope it will help others I spent so many hours.

[image]