# "failed to create jvm error code 6"

Tags: android, android-studio

i tried to make android studio work better in my pc using stackoverflow's previous articles, so i used this comment to try to solve this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39232021/4450923))

but when i re-launched android studio i get this error :

[image]

So, here we go again to find a solution to solve this new problem, i checked a lot of stackoverflow Q&A but it didn't solved!

so, give me a solution to make android studion work normally again, and how to make it work better because its struggling and working slowly.
**My pc specs:**

> System: Windows 8.1 - processor:i-5  - RAM: 4GB

Answer (score 1):

in my case with Win10 OS;
try deleting the file "studio64.exe.vmoptions" in the folder .AndroidStudio(xxx/ version).
The full path located in C:\Users\yourPCUserName.AndroidStudio2.2\studio64.exe.vmoptions

**) The file is containing

## custom Android Studio VM options, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration*